# How can a rocket approaching the Karman Line then return to earth faster than 53 m/s terminal velocity?

Tags: rockets, gravity, thrust

In the book, *How to Make a Spaceship: A Band of Renegades, an Epic Race and the Birth of Private Spaceflight* the opening chapter details the June 2004 attempt to take *SpaceShipOne* to the Karman Line.

The chapter also recounts a story of the X-15, piloted by Mike Adams in 1967, re-entering the earth's atmosphere at Mach 5 and breaking up in a violent spin. This is used as a warning to the reader about the dangers that Melvill is facing in *SpaceShipOne*.

How does a vehicle, having exhausted it's primary thrust, return to earth at a greater speed than terminal velocity?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

53 m/s is the approximate [terminal velocity of a human skydiver](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1998/JianHuang.shtml).

The [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity#Examples) of a [7-ton metal dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15#Specifications) is quite a bit higher. Larger objects tend to be affected less by atmospheric drag than smaller ones, all other things being equal. Terminal velocity also increases with altitude because the air is thinner.

Assuming 7000 kg mass, 3.5 m<sup>2</sup> cross section, and coefficient of drag 0.3 (educated guesses for the X-15), [this online terminal velocity calculator](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/eng/aerospace/terminal) gives 295 m/s terminal velocity at sea level (about 0.9 mach). At 25km altitude (air density 0.04), terminal velocity is about 1800 m/s or mach 5.

Comment: I thought all things had the same terminal velocity.  If we drop a book and a cannonball from a great height they land at the same time no?

Comment: @Venture2099 Not in atmosphere, no (do a feather and a cannonball land at the same time?). The retarding force from air resistance is proportional to cross-sectional area; the relative acceleration imparted by that force is inversely proportional to mass. For spheres of identical density, for example, cross sectional area goes up by the square of radius; mass goes up by the cube of radius, so drag-acceleration is inversely proportional to radius.

Comment: @Venture2099 The reason a demonstration with two metal balls from not too great a height can work is just that the effect of air resistance will be negligible for fairly massive objects at fairly low velocities.

Comment: @Venture2099 Do a skydiver with a parachute reach the ground at the same time as one **without** ?

Comment: @Antzi The last one to attempt such an experiment passed away before he could publish the results...

Comment: @Raptor That's why a good scientific study should always discriminate the researcher and the test subject.

Comment: Tell that to them: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-people-have-died-while-trying-to-find-out-the-taste-of-cyanide

Comment: Note that at 25 km altitude, the speed of sound is actually lower than at sea level, so 1800 m/s = Mach 6 or so at that height.

Comment: @Venture2099 If a book and cannonball hit the ground at the same time then they’re in a vacuum (or near-vacuum) and thus don’t _have_ a terminal velocity.

Comment: The problem is also that rockets are built precisely to reduce drag, so slowing them down to 'terminal velocity' takes quite a bit longer than it would for a person

Comment: Felix Baumgartener on his jump reached 1.3mm/h (megameters, yes, he was going thousands of kph). That terminal velocity is for a skydiver in "low" atmosphere, like what skydivers normally jump from -- you'll notice if you look into skydiving that they very rarely even wear masks in the open-door plane, because they're not too high that the air gets thin. +1 for explaining that's significantly different from the maximum speed attainable in atmosphere.

Comment: megameters = Mm; millimeters = mm.